# Exception: License 114440 License expired 2014-10-22 in LINK

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, licensing, bullseye

My MSDN license expired.  I logged into Microsoft, deleted all my old MSDN licenses from my account, and added a new invitation from my IT department.  I also installed the VS2013 Update3 installer and rebooted my machine.

At this point, Visual Studio shows me as being licensed (no temporary extension, just fully licensed) and I can build C# projects fine.  But whenever I try to link a C++ program I get the error:

```
Exception: License 114440 License expired 2014-10-22
error MSB6006: "link.exe" exited with code 1.
```

I also tried giving VS the product key from the MSDN page, but behavior is the same.

How can I mollify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio was not to blame!  I had installed a trial version of the Bullseye C++ code coverage tool, which supplies its own version of the CL and LINK tools.  These are what had expired.  I first noticed that CL and LINK worked fine in the VS2013 native tools shell, and then I went back and found that I still had the Bullseye plugin enabled in Visual Studio itself.

Oops.